# NVDA screen-reader skips pronunciation of outer 'div' when moving backward (using Shift+Tab)

Tags: html, css, firefox, nvda

Here is my code snippet

```css
div { border: 1px solid orange; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="header" tabindex="0">Header</div>
<div id="slats-component" tabindex="0">
  <div id="totals-wrapper">Total [2]</div>
  <div id="slats-component-body">
    <div id="slat" tabindex="0">Slat1</div>
    <div id="slat" tabindex="0">Slat2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using only NVDA and only for FireFox.

Here is the actual behavior (what you do / focused element id / what NVDA reads):

- when moving forward (using `Tab`):

  1. Navigate to Header / **header** / Header
  2. `Tab` / **slats-component** / Total [2], Slat 1, Slat 2
  3. `Tab` / **slat1** / Slat 1
  4. `Tab` / **slat2** / Slat 2
- when moving backward (using `Shift + Tab`):

  1. Navigate to Slat 2 / **slat2** / Slat 2
  2. `Shift + Tab` / **slat1** / Slat 1
  3. `Shift + Tab` / **slats-component** / [nothing]
  4. `Shift + Tab` / **header** / Header

**Actual behavior**: while moving backward on step #3 NVDA reads nothing

**Expected behavior**: on the same step NVDA reads: *Total [2], Slat 1, Slat 2*

Pure CSS/HTML solution is preferable. In the meantime the html-snippet above is a part of AngularJS directive's template, so another solution is also possible.

Comment: I don't use the Shit key very often :P

Comment: Actually it looks like an NVDA issue. Thus I've post it on [github NVDA issues page](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7522).
In the meantime I got rid of this DOM structure.